# Type-level wrapper for HList elements

Tags: scala, shapeless

Is it possible to create a type-level function that will provide a compact syntax for the type of an HList of Sets?

So that the following line:

```
val l: Set[Int] :: Set[String] :: Set[Boolean] :: HNil =
    Set(1, 2) :: Set("abc") :: Set(true, false) :: HNil
```

could be rewritten as:

```
val l: HListOfSets[Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil] =
    Set(1, 2) :: Set("abc") :: Set(true, false) :: HNil
```

Comment: You cannot just change the way the type is showed. If you declare that type separately and create values using a special constructor, then it will be like that, but it has nothing to do with existing `HList`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
type s_::[E, +T <: HList] = shapeless.::[Set[E], T]

val l: Int s_:: String s_:: Boolean s_:: HNil =
  Set(1, 2) :: Set("abc") :: Set(true, false) :: HNil
```

Comment: This approach is useful when we directly construct a new HList of Sets, but it fails if we get a type `L <: HList` as a parameter and then try to wrap it as `HListOfSets[L]`